# How to remove background when click on material-table action buttons

Tags: material-ui, material-table

I want to remove this background grey color when switching on or off in Material-Table.

Here is my table code.

[image]

Here is the code for material-table.When I inspect the code I see a button as a parent element of this Switch element. I am pretty sure this is due to that button element. I added a styling to remove the hover color and It's working fine but for this click event I am unable to change it.

here is the code for removing hover styling:

```
    rootTable: {
    "& .MuiIconButton-root": {
      backgroundColor:'transparent',
    },
    
  },

<div className={classes.rootTable}>
        <MaterialTable
                options={{
                    paging: false,
                    addRowPosition: 'first',
                    search: true,
                    showTitle: false,
                    doubleHorizontalScroll: true,
                    minBodyHeight: '65vh',
                    maxBodyHeight: '68vh',
                    actionsColumnIndex: columns.length
                }}
                style={{ width: '100%' }}
                actions={[
                    //rowData => ({
                    //     icon: (rowData.companyAddress && rowData.companyAddress != null) ? "location_on"  : "location_off",
                    //     tooltip: "Update Address",
                    //     onClick: (event, rowData) => dispatch(Actions.setSelectedCompanyData(rowData))
                    //   })
                    rowData => ({
                        icon:()=>RenderSwitch(rowData),
                        tooltip: "Supprimer cet accès Net",
                    }),
                ]}
                components={{
                    Toolbar: props => {
                        const propsCopy = { ...props };
                        propsCopy.showTitle = false;

                        return (
                            <Grid container direction="row" alignItems={"center"}>
                                <Grid container item xs={3} justify={'flex-end'}>
                                  {t('LBL.NUMBER_OF_LOGINS')+": "+ data.length}
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid container item xs={3} justify={'flex-end'}>
                                    {renderPasswordVisibleToggle()}
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item xs={6}>
                                    <MTableToolbar {...propsCopy} />
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        );
                    }
                }}
                isLoading={loading}
                localization={{
                    pagination: {
                        labelDisplayedRows: `{from}-{to} ${t('TBL.PAGGING.TO')} {count}`,
                        labelRowsPerPage: t('TBL.PAGGING.LBL')
                    },
                    header: {
                        actions: ['Actions']
                    },
                    body: {
                        emptyDataSourceMessage: t('TBL.EMPTY_RECORDS_MESSAGE'),
                        addTooltip: t('TBL.ADD'),
                        editTooltip: t('TBL.EDIT'),
                        editRow: {
                            deleteText: 'Voulez-vous supprimer cette ligne?',
                            cancelTooltip: t('TBL.CANCEL'),
                            saveTooltip: t('TBL.SAVE')
                        }
                    },
                    toolbar: {
                        searchTooltip: t('TBL.SEARCH'),
                        searchPlaceholder: t('TBL.SEARCH')
                    }
                }}
                columns={columns.map(column => {
                    column.title = t(column.translate);
                    return column;
                })}
                data={data}
                editable={{
                    onRowAdd: !loggedUser.role.includes("ROLE_SUB_USER") ? (newData) =>
                    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        newData.submitted = true;
                        if (newData.siret.length!==14) {
                            setNameError({
                                error: true,
                                label: "required",
                                helperText: t('LBL.INVALID_COMPANY_ID') ,
                                validateInput: true,
                            });
                            reject();
                            newData.submitted = undefined;
                            return;
                        }
                        newData.submitted = undefined;

                        if (isDevelopmentEnvironment || newData?.societe?.includes('test-qa')){
                            dispatch(Actions.saveNewLogin(newData,resolve));
                        }else {
                            const url = apiConfig.baseUrl + '/api/company-login/check-login-status';
                            axios
                                .post(url, newData, { validateStatus: () => true })
                                .then(response => {
                                    if (response?.data?.validLogin) {
                                        setCreateData(newData);
                                        setTimeout(() => {
                                            resolve();
                                        }, 600);
                                    } else {
                                        dispatch(MessageActions.showMessage({
                                            message: t("LBL.ERROR_MESSAGE"),
                                            variant: 'error'
                                        }));
                                        reject();
                                    }
                                })
                                .catch(error => {
                                    console.error(error);
                                    reject();
                                });
                        }
                    }) : null,
                    onRowUpdate: newData => {
                        return new Promise(resolve => {
                            dispatch(Actions.updateCompanyLogin(newData,resolve));
                        })
                    }
                }}
                icons={{
                    Add: forwardRef((props, ref) => (
                        <Fab ref={ref} {...props} className={classes.iconButton} aria-label="add">
                            <AddIcon />
                        </Fab>
                    ))
                }}
            />
</div>
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55846015/how-to-remove-background-ripple-effect-from-custom-action-button-in-material-tab) might be helpful.
Also, Please add the relevant code in the question, so, the people can see what you've done already and provide suggestions/answers.

Comment: I have added more details.